# regroup in django-template mongo values

Tags: python, django, mongodb

This type of question is asked before here, but I tried and couldn't make it work.

I want to regroup mongodb values and display it on html.

***This is how I want:***

**Item1:**
*attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4,*

**Item2:**
*attr1, attr2, attr3,*

**Item3:**
*attr1, attr2*

***but instead, it is displayed like this:***

**Item1:** *attr1, attr2, attr3,*

**Item2:** *attr1, attr2,*

**Item1:** *attr4*

**Item3:** *attr1, attr2*

**Item2:** *attr3*

How should i correctly group it.

*Below is what I tried.*

**views.py**

```
def alllocations(request):
  mydb = client.sdkLocationDataDB
  data = mydb.locationDataColl
  values = data.find()
  return render(request, 'alllocations.html', {"values":values})
```

**html:**

```
{% regroup values by ownName as ownName_list %}
{% for ownName in ownName_list %}
<h3>{{ownName.grouper}}</h3>
{% for items in ownName.list %}
<p>{{items}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I may be missing some obvious points but any help to the right direction will be grateful.

**EDIT:** I tried `values = [values]` in `views.py` but no luck. Also, dictsort too doesn't work.

This is the screenshot [image: problem screenshot]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. looking at your expected result, how about using `.aggregate()` instead of `find()`? But again you question is unclear.

Comment: @user3100115, I have attached screenshot for better understanding. I simply want to regroup mongodb values in django-template. Any approach that works will be good enough as mentioned by you about `aggregrate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the mistake, `dictsort` didn't work for `ownName` but worked for `userId`. Also, sorting it in views is equally well.

```
values = data.find().sort("ownName",1)
```

and then, everything comes as I wanted.